# Post users' all inputs into database and display the last input but do not replace

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table where user can input dates. It correctly goes to database and Replace the previous input and display in the table.

Now I want to store all the user's inputs in database and display only the last input. I have a button called update.

I believe that it is something with this update button. Hope You can help me to solve this. Please help. Thanks

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE `fiber`.`fiberexcel` SET Quotation11='$_POST[A12]',
ApprovalJFSRequest13='$_POST[A14]', 
ApprovalJFSReceived15='$_POST[A16]',
JFSDone17='$_POST[A18]',
OFNtoSAQ19='$_POST[A20]',
ApprovalDrawing21='$_POST[A22]',
TechEvaluation23='$_POST[A24]' ,  
AllQuotationsRecieved25='$_POST[A26]' ,
MailConfirmationWorkStart27='$_POST[A28]',
POReceived28='$_POST[A29]',
WorkApprovalRequest30='$_POST[A31]',
WorkApprovalReceived32='$_POST[A33]',
IBWStarted34='$_POST[A35]',
IBWCompleted36='$_POST[A37]',
HandOverContractor38='$_POST[A39]',
RequestAuthority40='$_POST[A41]',
EstimateReceivedDialog42='$_POST[A43]',
SystemPRRequested44='$_POST[A45]',
SystemPODone46='$_POST[A47]',
DocumentToFIN48='$_POST[A49]',
PaymentFin50='$_POST[A51]',
PaymentContractor52='$_POST[A53]',
PaymentAuthority54='$_POST[A55]',
OSPWorkStart56='$_POST[A57]',
OSPWorkComplete58='$_POST[A59]',
TestingCompleted60='$_POST[A61]',
Remarks65='$_POST[Remarks]'
WHERE  `fiberexcel`.`SiteID0`='$_POST[hidden]'";

//echo($UpdateQuery);

mysqli_query($conn, $UpdateQuery);

};
```

Comment: First step, execute one query with $_POST vars directly inside, its really harmful. You allow code injection. Try to filter it.

Comment: You want to update or insert?

Comment: I want to insert user inputs into database. But display only the input user added at last.

Answer (score 0):

First at all you have to change UPDATE query to INSERT query, make that primary key to be autoincrement as well. After that you can simply do

```
ORDER BY DATE_TO_ORDER LIMIT 1,1;
```

this will give you only 1st record which is actually newest insert to database.

And please dont use $_POST directly in your query because your code is now SQL injectable. Make new variables for each post and then insert them in query.

I really recommend you to use PDO [prepared statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

By 'change UPDATE to INSERT':

UPDATE QUERY:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

INSERT QUERY:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Comment: Thanks Aleksandar. I changed if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$InsertQuery = "UPDATE `fiber`.`fiberexcel` SET Quotation11='$_POST[A12]', Is this correct? It still replace the input in database

Comment: @Sugs unfortunately no... let me update my answer please.